# Want to purchase electric range unassembled

Tags: stove

We have put in storm doors at front and rear entrances that have finished frames that narrow the doorway to under 26 inches.

A 30 inch free electric range is our pick for a new range.

Also we have heard of some appliance manufacturers that have special collapsed uninstalled range to homes, condos, etc with very small doors.

Anyone have name(s) of (a) manufacturer(s)?

Comment: Can you take the closer and/or chains off the storm door, so it opens all the way? I've had to do this when moving before, and I've also had to take the main door off the hinges entirely; neither is very hard to do. If the opening of the doorway itself is large enough to get the appliance through, this is *significantly* easier than disassembly of an appliance (or rather, every major appliance in your house, since 30~32" widths are quite common).

Answer (score 2):

I Googled for a few minutes and can't find anything you might be interested in, unless it is something like [this](http://www.armynavydeals.com/asp/products_details.asp?SKU=WYFVAPORAF&ST=2&Brunton%20Vapor%20AF%20All-Fuel%20Stove) (an unassembled "stove"):

[image]

Of course for any given range, taking off the oven door is something housewives are expected to do for deep Spring cleaning.  That removes a couple inches off the depth which should make the side profile about 24 inches.   Here is a side view of our GE Profile range:

[image]

Those handles stick out 2.1 inches.  The oven drawer and door slide out and can be removed without any tools.  The knobs stick out 1.0 inches but they easily slide off leaving shafts which don't protrude any more than the ridge below it.  This is a gas oven and range, but the female connector on the back doesn't extend beyond the chassis, so without a gas appliance line, the fore to aft distance without handles is 24.25 inches and 26.35 inches with the handles.  So this as large as can be standard size appliance (30 inch) would easily fit through your door—sideways.

Comment: Wallyk, I doubt that will work. Most times there is an overhang above the door, so removing it will not reduce the depth.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey:  I added our particular experience.  Removing the door and drawer make the side profile 24.25 inches.

Comment: Hmmm. Surprising, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that.  The oven is a little narrower depth wise.  26-28 it should fit thought the door if you can take off oven handle. Take a tape measure when you go shopping.

Comment: Agreed. I've never seen one able to be disassembled. Not a good idea IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've never seen one that ships disassembled, aside from buying one that will fit, or a separate range and oven, one option might be to hire an appliance service person to disassemble and reassemble it for you. Doing it yourself would likely void the warranty and could be dangerous if you don't reassemble correctly.